# iOS Ad-Hoc Install fails with proper provisions made

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I have done this a dozen times successfully and cannot figure out what is wrong for this instance. I created the deployment certificate, added my devices, and then created my ad-hoc profile using the deployment cert and all devices.

I have a website that allows the user to install the profile and app. The app starts to install and gets to where it is almost done and then it just sits there. It fails for all devices with different flavors of iOS on them.

Any ideas what could be wrong? This is the console output where (altered) line 3 is bugging me. I think this is the primary failure point and I am investigating further. It works fine from my desktop.

```
Aug  5 09:08:29 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini installd[62] <Notice>: 0x3cf000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.marketforce.Auditor
Aug  5 09:08:36 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini profiled[213] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping. 
Aug  5 09:08:37 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini securityd[78] <Notice>: http asynchttp_timer_proc Timeout during GET http://ocsp.apple.com/ocsp-wwdr01/ThisHasBeenChangedInTheInterestOfSecurity%2BThisHasAlsoBeenAlteredForSecuritym67h1P0%3D.
Aug  5 09:08:37 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini installd[62] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'Adhoc Distribution'
Aug  5 09:08:37 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini installd[62] <Error>: 0x3cf000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.nkJObR/foo_extracted/Payload/Auditor.app/Auditor: 0xe8008016
Aug  5 09:08:37 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini installd[62] <Error>: 0x3cf000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.nkJObR/foo_extracted/Payload/Auditor.app
Aug  5 09:08:37 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini installd[62] <Error>: 0x3cf000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Aug  5 09:08:37 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini itunesstored[89] <Error>: 0x1c3e000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Aug  5 09:08:37 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini itunesstored[89] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Aug  5 09:08:37 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini lsd[166] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.marketforce.Auditor
Aug  5 09:08:37 MFI-Test-iPad-Mini itunesstored[89] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.marketforce.Auditor.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed;
```

Comment: I don't recall end users having to install a profile for ad-hoc. Users typically install through iTunes. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is a way for internal users at the company to install our app on test devices. That's why I'm using an ad-hoc profile instead of the app store deployment profile.

Comment: Our users install ad-hoc deployed apps by downloading the .ipa and installing through iTunes.

Comment: you do need a profile to do ad-hoc downloads, and from the error, something isn't going right with your provisioning profile, or your "keychain-access-groups" entitlement. Double check your provisioning profile and that entitlment.

Comment: I'm not using any special entitlements so this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app was originally created under a developer's appleID and the published in the Business To Business site. The developer left the company and the company created an appleID to be used for the company's development purposes. (Which is what should have been done to begin with).

The app was then transferred to the company's ID however the transfer didn't work right as it left the AppID under the old developer account so any attempt to use certificates and profiles against either account was doomed to failure while using the original AppID. To do any sort of internal deployment, a different AppID had to be created.

After Apple finally got the app transfer fully complete, all was good and the original AppID could once again be used.

Answer (score 0):

When I hit ad-hoc distribution errors, I have a couple troubleshooting steps to try to narrow it down.

Can you install just the provisioning profile? You should have either a developer or a distribution profile (depending, often times I install both to be sure).
Can you install the app via the iPhone Configuration Utility?

Answering those two questions will point you in the right direction at least. Good luck!